# .val() not grabbing value entered into input

Tags: jquery, input

Having issues grabbing current value from two inputs.  I keep getting undefined when trying to get the current value.  Have never had problems with this before and cannot seem to get this one.

```
<label id="lblName" for="txtVehicleName"  class="vehicle_label">Vehicle Name:</label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtVehicleName" name="txtVehicleName" class="vehicle_input_required" maxlength="200" value="" />
<span id="qVName" class="question">?</span>
<div class=".clearfix"></div>

<label id="lblCategorization" for="txtCategorization"  class="vehicle_label">Categorization:</label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtCategorization" class="vehicle_input_required" />
<span id="qCat" class="question">?</span>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnNext_VI").on("click", function () {
      event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
      var Categorization = $("#txtCategorization").val();
      var VehicleName = $("#txtVehicleName").val();
      alert(Categorization);
      alert(VehicleName);

      if (validate("VI")) {
         $("#divVI").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#divPU").fadeIn(100);
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an asp.NET page using a master page?

Comment: Protip: `console.log()`, `alert()` is not a debugging function!

Comment: yes it is using a master page

Comment: Where is `btnNext_VI` for a start? Missing here. Also, works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/9qgntxau/

Comment: what is the event u are using in funtion .. u need to pass in as function argument

Comment: See the viewsource of the page and verify the HTML id. safer side use ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textbox is a server field, use the `ClientID` property:

```
var Categorization = $("#<%= txtCategorization.ClientID %>").val();
```

If you inspect that `input` on page render, you'll notice the ID is not `txtCategorization` - but a server generated ID.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I actually knew this but for some reason had escaped me.  Thank you everyone for your quick answers

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` (ASP.Net 4.0+) so that the control id will not be changed. You can use it in external js file also

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtCategorization" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**ASP.Net < 4.0,** But this line cannot be used in external js file as it uses inline asp.net syntax

```
$("#<%= txtCategorization.ClientID %>").val()
```